# MahApps.Metro Window causes error when closing

Tags: wpf, window, mahapps.metro

I upgraded my application to MahApps.Metro but I get a really obscure error. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Login : MetroWindow
{
    public bool AllowAutomaticLogin { get; set; }

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        AllowAutomaticLogin = true;
    }

    public Login(bool allowAutomaticLogin)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        AllowAutomaticLogin = allowAutomaticLogin;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        DataContext = new LoginViewModel(CloseWindow, AllowAutomaticLogin);
    }

    private void CloseWindow(object obj)
    {
        GetWindow(this).Close();
    }

    ...other stuff that doesn't matter
}
```

In my view model I have the constructor:

```
public LoginViewModel(Action<object> closeWindow, bool allowAutomaticLogin)
    {
        AllowAutomaticLogin = allowAutomaticLogin;
        CloseWindow = closeWindow;
        Login = new RelayCommand(_Login);
        SwitchAccounts = new RelayCommand(_SwitchAccounts);
        if (AllowAutomaticLogin)
        {
            try
            {
                AttendanceAppServiceClient proxy = new AttendanceAppServiceClient();
                if (proxy.IsRegistered(Environment.UserName))
                {
                    Username = Environment.UserName;
                    IsRecognized = true;
                    RecognizedText = "You have been recognized as " + Username + ". Please provide your password.";

                    if (Properties.Settings.Default.AutomaticLogin)
                    {
                        var user = proxy.GetUser(Username);
                        var mainWindow = new MainWindow(user);
                        mainWindow.Show();
                        CloseWindow(null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    IsRecognized = false;
                }
                proxy.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

The point is if the PC username corresponds to a valid username in the database and if the app setting allows it, it just logs them in (simply closes the login window and opens the main window). Now, if the settings is false, you can just login as usual and fill in the username and password like this

```
private void _Login(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            AttendanceAppServiceClient proxy = new AttendanceAppServiceClient();
            User user;
            if ((user = proxy.IsValidUser(Username, SecurePassword)) != null)
            {
                var mainWindow = new MainWindow(user);
                mainWindow.Show();
                CloseWindow(null);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials. Try again.");
            }
            proxy.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Basically this piece of code:

```
var mainWindow = new MainWindow(user);
mainWindow.Show();
CloseWindow(null);
```

is just the same. But if I let the AllowAutomaticLogin setting in the view constructor true it gives me this

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: window
```

but if I set it false and login as usual, in goes through the _Login method and closes and opens the new window properly. The stack trace is:

```
at System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper..ctor(Window window)
at ControlzEx.Behaviors.WindowChromeBehavior.AssociatedObject_SourceInitialized(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\projects\controlzex\src\ControlzEx\Behaviors\WindowChromeBehavior.cs:line 323
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Window.OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at AttendanceApp.App.Main()
```

Just to be clear, it worked perfectly fine before I added the MetroWindow (all I did was change the base class to MetroWindow and add controls:MetroWindow instead of Window). What may be the issue.

Comment: Why don't you simply call `this.Close()` in the `CloseWindow` method?

Comment: I get the same result, I tried. It seems that it just won't close the metro window unless the Loaded even has finished, or so I presume, because I still haven't fixed it, I just put a bandaid on it but it would be helpful to solve the problem

Comment: Why are you trying to close the window before it has been loaded?

Comment: Well, if a certain condition is met, I don't need the window anymore and I simply open a new one and close this one. With normal windows it works, with MetroWindow it doesn't...

Comment: Please provide a repo of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First of all I don't know what a repo is and secondly I posted all the relevant information in this thread, there's nothing more to add. You asked me why I'm trying to close the window before it's loaded but the answer is already in the code...

Comment: Try to click on the link I provided. It explains how to ask a question on SO and what a MCVE is.